# Ajax is not working on live server

Tags: php, ajax

i have a contact form attached with a php mailer library. i am trying to send email without page refresh. for this purpose i used Ajax. its working perfect but on localhost. Its stop working when i upload it to server.
here is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML lang="en">

<HEAD>
<TITLE>TechWare House | Contact us</TITLE>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $(document).on('submit', '#form_contact', function()
    {   
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'email.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
                   {
                    $(".form-contact-result").fadeIn(0).show(function()
                        {
                        $(".form-contact-result").html(data);
                        });
                   }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
            <div class="form-contact-result"></div><!-- message div -->
            <form id="form_contact" method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name:" id="name" name="name" required>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail:" id="email" name="email" required>
                    <textarea rows=8 name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message:" required></textarea>
                    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
                </div>
             </div>

            </form>

</BODY></HTML>
```

would someone explain the reason why its stop working on live server?

Comment: The problem comes from your email.php script. Use your console to check errors from Ajax requests. I think your web server can't send emails through PHP.

Comment: Any error, so anyone can help?

Comment: If the problem starts when using the live server instead of the test server, the problem would related to the server-side code so posting only your html and javascript with a "doesn't work" error description is not really helptul.

Comment: @VincentDecaux i am using phpmailer libray and its working on booth localhost and live sever if i don't use ajax.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions nothing showing on screen actually its not working at all

Comment: Use F12 Developer Console in the browser to check the ajax call.

Comment: @jeroen sir how can i check if server is not processing JS at all

Comment: still looking for answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys the problem was not with Ajax, its was server issue. server install few updates and it needs to re-start. i just give a restart and now its working perfect.

thanks for corporation